# Computation of Hankel Transform using FFT (Fourier)

Tags: numerics, fourier-analysis, integral-transforms, optics

To address circularly symmetric cases of 2-D Fourier Transformations, the so-called Hankel Transform can be applied (for a detailed derivation of the relation between the 2-D Fourier transform and the 1-D Hankel transform see [Link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HankelTransform.html)).

For more complex or numerically tabulated radial functions, a numeric implementation of the Hankel transform (similiar to FFT) would come in handy.  There has been an interesting proposal by Oppenheim from 1980 (full text is available on the [Web](http://www.rle.mit.edu/dspg/documents/computation_1980.pdf)) that explains the use of the highly optimized FFT algorithm to do the Hankel transform.

Is anybody aware of such an implementation of the Hankel transform in Mathematica?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0898-1221(93)90081-6), by any chance?

Comment: Interesting reference, mentions multiple algorithms including the algorithm by Oppenheim, which I referenced above, thanks for pointing me on it. Unfortunately all of the algorithms would need some coding. I'll need to check which of the algorithms is most suited for my problem (radial symmetric diffraction at complex apertures).

Comment: "Unfortunately all of the algorithms would need some coding." - I know, I'm just saying you've plenty of options. Is using `NIntegrate[]` too slow for your needs?

Comment: Sure, there are plenty of options. I'm just looking for something optimized readily available in Mathematica since for diffraction calculations I would need hundreds of iterations over the Hankel transform to calculate the optical near field of cylindrical apertures. NIntegrate[] is for sure one option, I'll just would like to do a review on available options before I reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Finally I found the most promising algorithm proposed in this really good reference [Manuel Guizar-Sicairos and Julio C. Gutiérrez-Vega, "Computation of quasi-discrete Hankel transforms of integer order for propagating optical wave fields," J. Opt. Soc. Am. A 21, 53-58 (2004)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1364/JOSAA.21.000053).
The authors call the algorithm pth-order quasi-discrete Hankel Transform (pQDHT) and it is perfectly suited for vector implementation within *Mathematica*.

The references uses the following definitions for the Hankel Transform:

$$f_2(\nu)=2 \pi  \int_0^{\infty } f_1(r) J_p(2 \pi  \nu  r) r \, dr$$

and its inverse

$$f_1(r)=2 \pi  \int_0^{\infty } f_2(\nu) J_p(2 \pi  r \nu) \nu \, d\nu$$

My code for the Transform and its inverse looks as follows:

```
DiscreteHankelTransform[f1_, p_, Np_, rmax_] := 
  Module[{a, aNp1, rv, uv, res, umax, T , J, F1, F2},
  a = Table[N[BesselJZero[p, n]], {n, 1, Np}];
  aNp1 = BesselJZero[p, Np + 1];
  umax = aNp1/(2 Pi rmax);
  rv = a/(2 Pi umax);
  uv = a/(2 Pi rmax);
  J = Abs[BesselJ[p + 1, a]];
  T = BesselJ[p, TensorProduct[a, a]/(2 Pi  rmax umax)]/(
  TensorProduct[J, J] Pi rmax umax) ;
  F1 = (If[MatchQ[Head[f1], List], f1, f1[rv]] rmax)/J;
  F2 = T.F1;
  Return[Transpose[{uv, J/umax F2}]];
];

InverseDiscreteHankelTransform[f2_, p_, Np_, umax_] := 
 Module[{a, aNp1, rv, uv, res, rmax, T , J, F1, F2},
 a = Table[N[BesselJZero[p, n]], {n, 1, Np}];
 aNp1 = BesselJZero[p, Np + 1];
 rmax = aNp1/(2 Pi umax);
 rv = a/(2 Pi umax);
 uv = a/(2 Pi rmax);
 J = Abs[BesselJ[p + 1, a]];
 T = BesselJ[p, TensorProduct[a, a]/(2 Pi rmax umax)]/(
  TensorProduct[J, J] Pi rmax umax) ;
 F2 = (If[MatchQ[Head[f2], List], f2, f2[uv]] umax)/J;
 F1 = T.F2;
 Return[Transpose[{rv, J/rmax F1}]];
];
```

with f1 and f2 defined as pure functions of r and u respectively. Both functions can be specified as lists of x and y values too. p is the order of the transform, Np is the number of points used for the non zero part of the functions and their transform and rmax and umax are the maximum radial values for which f1 is nonzero and umax the maximum spatial frequency for which f2 is nonzero respectively.
A test case is the example function $\frac{\text{sinc}(2 \pi \gamma r)}{2 \pi \gamma r}$ mentioned in the above reference.
This test can be carried out as

```
f = Sin[2 Pi g #]/(2 Pi g #) &;
F0[u_, p_, g_] = 
 Piecewise[{
   {HankelTransform[f, u, p, {p >= 0, 0 < u < g}], 0 <= u < g},
   {Sin[p ArcSin[g/u]]/(2 Pi g Sqrt[u^2 - g^2]), u > g},
   {Infinity, u == g}
  }, Null]
SetAttributes[F0, Listable];

dF01 = DiscreteHankelTransform[f /. g -> 5, 1, 256, 3.0];
dF04 = DiscreteHankelTransform[f /. g -> 5, 4, 256, 3.0];
dF01max = Max[Abs[dF01]];
dF04max = Max[Abs[dF04]];
dynerr1 = Transpose[{dF01[[;; , 1]], 20 Log10[Abs[F0[#[[1]], 1, 5] - #[[2]]]/dF01max] & /@dF01}];
dynerr4 = Transpose[{dF04[[;; , 1]], 20 Log10[Abs[F0[#[[1]], 4, 5] - #[[2]]]/dF04max] & /@dF04}];
GraphicsGrid[{
 {Show[
  Plot[F0[u, 1, 5], {u, 0, 20}, 
    PlotRange -> {-0.005, 0.05}, 
    Exclusions -> None, 
    Frame -> True, 
    Axes -> False, 
    FrameLabel -> {"u", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(2\)]\)[\[Nu]]"}, 
    PlotLabel -> "HT, p\[Equal]1"],
  ListPlot[dF01]], 
  ListLinePlot[dynerr1, 
   Frame -> True, 
   Axes -> False, 
   FrameLabel -> {"\[Nu]", "dB"}, 
   PlotLabel -> "e(\[Nu]), p\[Equal]1", 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {-180, 0}}]}, 
{Show[
  Plot[F0[u, 4, 5], {u, 0, 20}, 
   PlotRange -> {-0.03, 0.03}, 
   Exclusions -> None, 
   Frame -> True, 
   Axes -> False, 
   FrameLabel -> {"\[Nu]", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(2\)]\)[\[Nu]]"}, 
   PlotLabel -> "HT, p\[Equal]4"], ListPlot[dF04]], 
  ListLinePlot[dynerr4, 
   Frame -> True, 
   Axes -> False, 
   FrameLabel -> {"\[Nu]", "dB"}, 
   PlotLabel -> "e(\[Nu]), p\[Equal]4", 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {-180, 0}}]}}, 
   ImageSize -> Large]
```

Which yields a comparison between the analytical Hankel transform of the sinc function and the discrete version including the dynamic error of the discrete transform as outlined in Fig. 1 of the reference.
[image: Fig. 1 of Sicairos 2004].

This discrete Transform is perfectly suited for the simulation of the wave propagation through radial symmetric apertures. One can get very nice results of the propagation of Bessel beams as depicted in Fig. 3 of Sicairos:
[image]

Comment: Might be a good idea to name the authors and the article title in the text, and use [the DOI URL](http://dx.doi.org/10.1364/JOSAA.21.000053) as the link target. The bare word "reference" is not very indicative of where the link will go, and you never know when opticsinfobase.org might change their URL scheme in the future.

Comment: Done, I was a bit sloppy in the reference you're right..

Comment: Rainer, can you share anything regarding performance of your implementation of the Henkel transform? I.e., how much time does it take to calculate a field profile at one z coordinate. I am glad I found this post, as I have run in to the same problem myself.
Thanks.
P.

Comment: @Pavel I have converted your "answer" into a comment.  Answer posts are intended to be used strictly for that.  The designers of StackExchange want you to build some "reputation" points before you get [the privilege to comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).  I'm not sure I agree with that policy but it is beyond my power to change it.  I encourage you to participate by asking and answering questions and soon this will be a non-issue.

Comment: @Pavel With only 20 points you will be able to [chat](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) which is a better way to discuss things.

Comment: @Pavel the Algorithm is rather efficient since it uses e.g. precomputed Bessel roots and a matrix multiplication approach. As an example a radial Crosssection with 1024 mesh points radially and 250 z steps takes a few seconds on a typical quad core machine. I did not invest any effort into speeding up the code though. I suppose there is plenty of headroom for speed optimization

Comment: I think the `HankelTransform` in the definition of `F0` should be `DiscreteHankelTransform`?

Comment: @xzczd no, since the point is to compare the analytical HT with the discrete.

Comment: @yuriyi `HankelTransform` is introduced in _2017(11.1)_, while this answer is last edited in _2013_: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HankelTransform.html

Comment: @xzczd damn you are right!
on a related note: Rainer mentioned that _Both functions can be specified as lists of x and y values too_ but then the points in which the functions are evaluated have to correspond to the zeros of the Bessel function, right?

Comment: @yuriyi Yeah, the algorithm is just not designed for dealing with arbitrary discrete data, if I've understood the original paper correctly.

Comment: @xzczd and yuriyi: No, the algorithm is designed to deal with arbitrary discrete data. The main limitation is that the data is zero outside a given maximum radius R: $f_1(r\geq R)=0$ which is equivalent to the data just extending over a limited region $0\leq r\leq R$

Comment: Well, one can of course interpolates arbitrary discrete data, but that's another story, isn't it? If the algorithm can deal with abitrary data **directly**, could you add an example? Also, could you add some explanation for the `HankelTransform`?

Comment: @xzczd: The example in my answer above (Fig. 3 of Sicairos) is the hankel transform of an initial discrete dataset along r (at position 0 on the x-axis). The function HankelTransform is described in the Mathematica documentation and its definition is also shown in my answer above.

Comment: ……I'm sorry, but I'm afraid Fig. 3 doesn't approve anything, given the source code for generating it isn't included in the post. Also, as mentioned in [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26233/computation-of-hankel-transform-using-fft-fourier/27353?noredirect=1#comment485259_27353), `HankelTransform` isn't a built-in function when you write this answer.

Comment: Responding to your comment on arbitrary discretized data: i am pretty sure the function to be transformed has to be evaluated at specific points (defined by the zeros of Bessel function). That is the idea behind the proposed algorithm: define Hankel tranform through Bessel series. Please consult the original paper.

Comment: @xzczd and @ yuriyi. You are right that you have to evaluate the function to transfer at the roots of a bessel function. However if you choose a large enough number of points for sampling (e.g. when interpolating a function) you'll notice that the dependency of the bessel function roots get practically linear and one can take evenly spaced radial components without any large loss of accuracy. If one has no evenly spaced data then it is still easily possible to interpolate any discrete dataset to evenly or even BesselZero spaced data.