# Computation of a Fresnel Diffraction pattern with Discrete Hankel Transform

Tags: numerics, fourier-analysis, integral-transforms, optics

In the next link: [Computation of Hankel Transform using FFT (Fourier)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26233/computation-of-hankel-transform-using-fft-fourier)

[Rainer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4431/rainer) implemented a great solution given in the next reference: Manuel Guizar-Sicairos and Julio C. Gutiérrez-Vega, "Computation of quasi-discrete Hankel transforms of integer order for propagating optical wave fields," J. Opt. Soc. Am. A 21, 53-58 (2004).

However he does not comment on how to calculate the propagation of an optical field (for example, how to reproduce Fig.3 from the reference he cited). So it would be nice if he or someone else could provide that example.

My main interest is to calculate the Fresnel Diffraction pattern of a circular aperture, however, I do not want to use a rectangular grid, but to solve the problem in polar coordinates (that is why I quote the other question and the author that posted the question)

Comment: This should be a comment with the answer you're referring to. The question doesn't say what post you mean. You can try to make this into an independent question by stating the problem clearly.

Comment: Thanks Jens, I just added the link to the problem I am refering to.

Comment: [This paper](https://dx.doi.org/10.6028/jres.103.030) covers a solution to the circular aperture diffraction pattern.